# bigger/larger number of mole(s)

Tags: grammatical-number

I keep re-reading this sentence and it just sounds so wrong to me. I am not quite sure which part is wrong but I am sure that there is something wrong with it. Am I supposed to use the word bigger or larger? and is moles supposed to be plural or singular?

"In the empirical formula, there would be a bigger number of moles of water per mole of anhydrous salt than if the compound had not spilled. "

Comment: "In the empirical formula, there would be more moles of water per mole of anhydrous salt than if the compound had not spilled. "

Comment: "*Number of*" calls for "*larger*", whether you're counting [moles](https://what-if.xkcd.com/imgs/a/4/moles_number_length.png), [moles](http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m6p6cqhPRJ1r0p3tb.jpg), or [moles](http://www.the-epilogue.com/wp-content/uploads/mole1.jpg).

Comment: @Dan: yes, but you wouldn't say an SUV's gas tank holds *"a larger number of gallons of gasoline"* than a subcompact's; you'd say *"more gallons of gasoline"* or just *"more gasoline"*. You should avoid the expression *"a larger number of"* for continuous quantities.

Comment: @Peter, I was taking OP at his word that he has to choose between "*a bigger number of <units>*" and "*a larger number of <units>*". Given (only) those two choices, he must select *larger*. Given a broader field, I completely agree that "*more*" is superior, as is terdon's "*greater*". By the way, I wouldn't say "*more gallons*" either, I'd say "*more gas*".

Answer (score 6):

A much better alternative would be *greater*:

> In the empirical formula, there would be a greater number of moles of water per mole of anhydrous salt than if the compound had not spilled.

Or, even better:

> In the empirical formula, there would be more moles of water per mole of anhydrous salt than if the compound had not spilled.

As for *moles* that should indeed be plural. A *mole* is a unit just like any other, so you would say *N moles* just like you would say *N meters*. In fact, given that a mole is, by definition, ~ `6.02e10` somethings, it is even more reasonable to have it pluralized than other units.

Comment: +1 all the same, but why "much better?"

Comment: @Kris well, because _bigger_ sounds plain wrong to me. I can't really tell you why, but _a bigger problem_ sounds fine while _a bigger number_ sounds like something a child would say. Popular usage as expressed [in this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bigger+number%2Cgreater+number%2Clarger+number&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbigger%20number%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgreater%20number%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clarger%20number%3B%2Cc0) certainly seems to agree with me.

Comment: "sounds plain wrong to me" is an opinion. I always maintained that NGrams should be used to support/substantiate a well defined answer, not as a resource to draw inference.

Comment: @Kris of course it's an opinion, I never claimed otherwise. I even said that "I can't tell you why". I also did not use an NGram in my answer but only in response to your comment. All I said was that it seems to agree with my opinion but if you don't like that, feel free to run a search on COCA where (if I understand the results correctly) _greater number_ has a collocation score of 6.3 versus 0.2 for _bigger number_.

Comment: Dress up your opinions in more official sounding language and it'll become fact.

Comment: @Kris I posted [a question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/209009/25030) about this in case you're interested.